# Rails: undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning rails using RailsTutorial.org and have run into an issue in [section 7.3.4](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-a_test_for_invalid_submission)

It wants me to run `get signup_path` but I get this error when I try:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for main:Object
from (irb):2
from /Users/reubenpressman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/reubenpressman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/reubenpressman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**This is what my routes.rb file looks like**

```
get "users/new"

root 'static_pages#home'
match '/signup',  to:'users#new',             via:'get'
match '/help',    to:'static_pages#help',     via:'get'
match '/about',   to:'static_pages#about',    via:'get'
match '/contact', to:'static_pages#contact',  via:'get'

resources :users
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: did you write the code for POST? what does your test code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just running this in irb?  If you so this needs to be in your RSpec test not just run from the console.  The "get" method here is part of RSpec: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec